# How to fix "MessageEncoder content type parsing is not supported" error when uploading to an asp.net iis server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, soap

I have an app where I upload an image to a asp.net webservice via soap. It works perfectly up to 4mb images and then fails with the following error:

Additional information: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded.

So I made these changes to my Web.config based on another stack overflow post, that said the default max upload size of asp.net was 4mb:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
```

From this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

But now I get this error:

Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Additional information: MessageEncoder content type parsing is not supported.

If I remove the changes to the Web.config then the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maxRequestLength is a value in kilobytes, whilst maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes. If you change this, be sure to keep them matching.

Answer (score 1):

The "MessageEncoder content type parsing is not supported." could be caused by defining a tag in your web.config file multiple times. From your lines above, ensure that there are not two 'httpRuntime' tags.

There is likely this pre-existing:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

Replace it with:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="16384" />
```